# Http/1.1 Internal Server Error 43549 Citrix Workspace Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: workspaces, 23.04, citrix

Thanks in advance for reading my question. I was using Ubuntu 22.04.2 and managed to install the Citrix Workspace application (also known as icaclient), and managed to login with difficulty, after exporting certificates from my browser.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 which I really like the new features in. However after installing the icaclient (Citrix Workspace app), I again had to go through the certificate features as assumed. But now, when I try to login to my university, it gives the following error:

**Http/1.1 Internal Server Error 43549**

I have seen various solutions posted to this but they are old, and none of them have worked for me. Even a fedora workaround did not.

I am unable to post on the Citrix forums, because I have to be a "University IT Staff Member", despite the fact that when I first installed it on 22.04.2 and had the certificate issue, the tech staff could not help me solve it. In fact, I had to give the solution to them after finding it on this forum!

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I know it is not server related as it works from Windows 11 (I dual boot).

Here is some of the verbose log:

```
2023-06-25 20:58:49.443 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Loading uri: https://adapt.adelaide.edu.au/nf/auth/doSaml?ctx=4eJ5p7AQfW5_rtOP3Tq_oJopD_4h2AHG8f7TsNB1NWYVQ8HPuPkGXERXkytMLI8FWq4nSjika5p2rx_i73RBvhL4UHZyhTpLhMtmore_uQG2sdr6Y91PAJEHQZZAXY4-HIpP6oDBykJvZpOGmoFJRuOzi_DhOIn1ffNUR-aw3fjW0htw-uVNkyZ3Ys3ErS2NnIf952uXWn0%3D;wv=1; 
2023-06-25 20:58:49.447 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Finished loading Page
 
2023-06-25 20:58:49.450 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Page load started.. 
2023-06-25 20:58:50.712 [UIDW3E] <P28314> citrix-WebKitWebProcess: WindowObjectCleared 
2023-06-25 20:58:50.713 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Loading uri: https://id.adelaide.edu.au/app/citrixnetscalergateway_saml/exk88fufvG5Mo4Uo53l6/sso/saml 
2023-06-25 20:58:50.958 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Finished loading Page
 
2023-06-25 20:58:51.004 [UIDW3E] <P28314> citrix-WebKitWebProcess: WindowObjectCleared 
2023-06-25 20:58:58.128 [UIDW3E] <P28314> citrix-WebKitWebProcess: WindowObjectCleared 
2023-06-25 20:59:14.130 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Page load started.. 
2023-06-25 20:59:14.332 [UIDW3E] <P28314> citrix-WebKitWebProcess: WindowObjectCleared 
2023-06-25 20:59:14.333 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Loading uri: https://id.adelaide.edu.au/login/token/redirect?stateToken=02.id.ziTMSFpBmiDsSW7cauwzb7nSXhEMPMPV6ih-yD13 
2023-06-25 20:59:14.380 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Loading of page failed with error Load request cancelled. Uri is https://id.adelaide.edu.au/login/token/redirect?stateToken=02.id.ziTMSFpBmiDsSW7cauwzb7nSXhEMPMPV6ih-yD13. Waiting for 2000000 secs before reloading. 
2023-06-25 20:59:16.381 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Reloading after failed attempt... 
2023-06-25 20:59:16.381 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Finished loading Page
 
2023-06-25 20:59:16.381 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Page load started.. 
2023-06-25 20:59:16.387 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Loading of page failed with error Frame load interrupted. Uri is https://adapt.adelaide.edu.au/cgi/samlauth. Waiting for 2000000 secs before reloading. 
2023-06-25 20:59:18.387 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Reloading after failed attempt... 
2023-06-25 20:59:18.387 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Finished loading Page
 
2023-06-25 20:59:18.390 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Page load started.. 
2023-06-25 20:59:18.445 [UIDW3E] <P28314> citrix-WebKitWebProcess: WindowObjectCleared 
2023-06-25 20:59:18.445 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Loading uri: https://adapt.adelaide.edu.au/cgi/samlauth 
2023-06-25 20:59:18.449 [UIDW3] <P28295> citrix-PrimaryAuthManager: Finished loading Page
```